# Inserting code snippets without the ` key

Tags: discussion, support

Here is my question! A couple of times, I wrote some thing like :

> "I'm using a foreach loop"

and someone comes and edits it to:

> "I'm using a `foreach` loop"

I can see the code when I'm editing it but the thing is that on my keyboard (French) I lack this key on my keyboard and I don't see any button to add this sort of quote, how can I do it?

(I did it here with a copy/paste from one of the guys that edited one of my posts but it would be cool if I don't have to always go to my old question and copy/paste the character from him!)

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_France.svg) your layout? If so, it looks like `Alt Gr+7`, possibly followed by a space should work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a keyboard shortcut for code markup:

<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>

When it is a short segment within a sentence it will add the back ticks ` around the selection. If the selection spans a few lines it will indent them 4 spaces.

An alternative is to type in the full Unicode escape:

<kbd>Alt + 0096</kbd>

Or simply use the full `<code>` tag, as [@casperOne mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114854/140951):

```
<code>foreach</code>
```

Answer (score 11):

While I prefer [Oded's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114848/140951) (it is the simplest, IMO), it should also be noted that in cases where you don't have a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (on a mobile device, for example) *or* a <kbd>`</kbd> and you can't find the [code format button at the top of the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114870/140951) (or it's not there, because again, you are on a mobile device) you can use the `<code>` HTML tag inline, like so:

```
<code>foreach</code>
```

Comment: Oh, can I +10 this? I post a bit from my mobile device, and I'm always forgetting about the `<code/>` tag so I can do inline code formatting.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I wish you could too, but of course, I'm a bit biased in this situation. =)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I'll donate +1 to your cause, so you just need to find +8 now :P

Comment: @AndrewBarber: +9, I can't vote on my own post. =)

Comment: @AndrewBarber if your mobile device is an iPhone, just hold down the apostrophe, the backtick appears on a pop-up menu. All you then have to worry about is the autocorrect removing the closing backtick for you...

Comment: @jrturton I should have included my device type (Android) in my comment. +1 anyway, since an iOS user might find that very useful.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Speaking of iOS, on my iPad the backtick character is a little hard to find on the virtual keyboard.  Tap the `.?123` key, then tap and hold the apostrophe key until a pop-up menu appears.  Backtick is the rightmost character in that menu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the <kbd>{}</kbd> button right on the formatting line above the question/answer box.  You know, the one that goes `B I | [globe+->] [quotes] {}...`

I just checked, and it doesn't actually show up on mobile devices... Can we get it there? It would be so useful.

Comment: I [mentioned it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114854/140951), but in the context where you *don't* have it (as in the mobile interface).

Comment: I missed that, perhaps you should add the `{}` somewhere.

Comment: Did you one better, I linked to your post.